# Retuning voice in full song so that singer is on-tune

Tags: software-rec, audio, music

I have some potentially great songs which are spoilt by singers who sing out of tune. Is there any easy to use (and hopefully cheap) software that 'corrects' the song so that they're not off-tune anymore? I don't mind too much if the backing is somewhat affected too, if the state-of-the-art isn't quite there yet.

I've heard of auto-tune of course, but as far as I know, that's before the song is put together (i.e. the singer's voice as an individual track, before it's mixed with the backing).

Answer (score 1):

There is no software that I know of that can extract a part of a sonic landscape and adjust only that part.  If you change the pitch of the singer, then the other instruments will be out of tune an equivalent amount.

Answer (score 0):

There's something called Hit'n'Mix which attempts to autotune (as well as try to split up all the individual instruments in a track. It's far from perfect, but worth a look:

http://hitnmix.com/

This sort of thing is a holy grail for sound I think. MusicRadar talks more about why it's so tricky:

http://beta.musicradar.com/news/tech/can-hitnmix-rip-up-and-rebuild-your-mp3s-385557